# Getting access to a hash - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get to data that I found in a binding.pry --- Here is is

```
[#<Stripe::Card:0x3fc1da530e18 id=card_1A4KjTLcGwfBVD0DjTHzDqsO> JSON: {
  "id": "card_1A4KjTLcGwfBVD0DjTHzDqsO",
  "object": "card",
  "address_city": null,
  "address_country": null,
  "address_line1": null,
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_line2": null,
  "address_state": null,
  "address_zip": "42424",
  "address_zip_check": "pass",
  "brand": "Visa",
  "country": "US",
  "customer": "cus_AP91mImLV1GIrS",
  "cvc_check": "pass",
  "dynamic_last4": null,
  "exp_month": 4,
  "exp_year": 2024,
  "fingerprint": "U2Lh3jtN9G5jgtxm",
  "funding": "credit",
  "last4": "4242",
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "tokenization_method": null
}]
```

I get all that data when I type this in the console: `context.customer.sources.data`

I've tried getting the `object` like this: `context.customer.sources.data[:object]` but that gives me this error => `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

How do I get to that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an array. so you should visit like `context.customer.sources.data[0][:object]` or `context.customer.sources.data[0].object`